# Prevent OpenCV function CreateVideoWriter from printing to console in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the Python bindings for OpenCV and have run into a little annoyance using CreateVideoWriter where when I call the function, it prints something similar to the below to the console and I can't seem to surpress it or ideally redirect it into a variable.

```
Output #0, avi, to 'temp/Temp.0433.avi':
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 9830 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25
 tbc
```

The command I'm using for testing is this:

```
self.file = cvCreateVideoWriter(nf,CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),self.fps,cvSize(320,240),1)
```

Although in the long run this app will have a control GUI its currently console based, the function is called every minute so this means its difficult to present even a simple menu or more useful status information without this call filling up the console.

Just wondering if anyone has experienced the same and/or has any ideas how I might be able to prevent this happening or can offer pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If all else fails, you could still hack around it by setting `sys.stdout.write` to `def dummy(_): pass` before calling it and restoring it later.

Comment: I just tried this by setting sys.stdout to a file object just before the call and then setting it back afterwards but its still going to the console which I don't truly understand!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way for you to do this is temporarily to redirect `sys.stdout` while calling the messy function -- anything else will force you to change the Python bindings.

Fortunately, this is easy: just use a `contextmanager`:

```
>>> import contextlib
>>> @contextlib.contextmanager
... def stdout_as(stream):
...     import sys
...     sys.stdout = stream
...     yield
...     sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
...
>>> print("hi")
hi
>>> import io
>>> stream = io.StringIO()
>>> with stdout_as(stream):
...     print("hi")
...
>>> stream.seek(0)
0
>>> stream.read()
'hi\n'
>>> print("hi")
hi
```

Comment: In answer to your question above, no its not writing to stderr either which is really confusing! I tried your suggestion of a context manager with stdout and stderr but its still displaying in the console.

Comment: @Duncan: hmm, that's odd. Unfortunately I can't immediately think of any reason why that could be. You might have to go and rootle around in the library's source code to see what it's doing. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far all the same, Python is still very much a learning curve for me! Have started looking back through OpenCV but will have to carry on tomorrow.

Comment: @Duncan: it has just struck me that you are using the openCV call as part of an instance attribute of a class, which makes me think you may not be redirecting stdout in the write place. What happens if you wrap the _entire_ program in a stdout redirector? (Or alternatively, do `sys.stdout = StringIO()`.)

Comment: Sorry, havnt had a chance to work on this for a week, yes your correct it is being called within a class however it also does the same if I run a simple test outside of a class. I tried wrapping the whole program with no success which has really got me, however the good news is that with a wx gui it doesnt pop up in the background which is what I was afraid of. So its annoying but I can work around it.